# XYZ Math Surface equations revision

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is it possible to revise XYZ Math parametric equations without deleting the object and starting over?

Comment: No, once primitives or object are created by operator, their parameters can no longer be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about reseting/applying global scale, rotation, location then you can press ctrl+A shortcut and select the needed option.

Answer (score 0):

The *XYZ Math Surface* from the *Extra Objects* add-on cannot be changed once another operation has been performed. Once the *Adjust Last Operation* panel is gone, the parameters can't be adjusted.